# Wordpress plugin files are loaded at every page. even if the plugin is not being used on that page?

Tags: wordpress

The plugins css files are loaded at every page even if the plugin is not being used there. How to fix this issue. This has increased the loading time of my website.

Comment: Duplicate [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165754/enqueue-scripts-styles-when-shortcode-is-present](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165754/enqueue-scripts-styles-when-shortcode-is-present)

Comment: Try this [https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_style]